# example of a proxy function with args

Tags: clojure

On the examples for [proxy](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/proxy), there is a binding for implementation class and interface, and another for `args`, which is usually left empty, ie:

```
(proxy [java.io.InputStream] ->[]<- (read [] -1))
```

Is there an example of a proxy call with inputs?

```
(proxy [java.io.InputStream] ->[arg0 arg1]<- (read [] -1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These params are for the `super(...)` call. Let's see an example:

You could use a JFrame proxy in its simplest form (no params), and it would work:

```
(proxy [JFrame] [])
```

But JFrame has another constructor when a window title is given. So you could use that:

```
(proxy [JFrame] ["Window title"])
```